# Error populating TableView with array: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I am trying to populate a UITableview with an NSarray.

I'm building an app in which users can search for companies, and the search results are returned by the database in an array. This makes that I can never predict how big this array will be.

when I'm testing the app, it gets stuck if there is only one search result. the error:

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c9a012 0x10d7e7e 0x1c4fb44 0x5268 0xd68fb 0xd69cf 0xbf1bb 0xcfb4b 0x6c2dd 0x10eb6b0 0x2296fc0 0x228b33c 0x228b150 0x22090bc 0x220a227 0x22acb50 0x31edf 0x1c62afe 0x1c62a3d 0x1c407c2 0x1c3ff44 0x1c3fe1b 0x1bf47e3 0x1bf4668 0x1bffc 0x1ddd 0x1d05)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

this is what my code looks like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return companies.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *celltitle=nil;
    if([companiesArray count]>1){
        celltitle = [[companiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"companyName"];
    }

    else
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[companiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"companyName"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[companiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"companyCity"];

        return cell;
    }

}
```

What should I do to prevent this error, if my array only contains 1 result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return companiesArray.count;
}
```

Comment: What is companies? What does CompaniesArray hold?

Comment: I didn't know that could be the problem! it's solved, working perfect now. Thank you!!

Comment: Its my pleasure. And i hope you got your answer.

Comment: companies is the search result in a NSDictionary and companiesArray is the search result in an NSArray. i was experimenting which was the best, the NSDictionary of the NSArray to use in a tableview. i'm a beginner so i wasn't sure about that.

Comment: @imagine digital if you got your solution then accept this answer

Comment: yes, I wanted to do that, but it told me to wait 9 minutes, this is the first time i checked since then. Thank you very much!